# Configurar pgAgent - instalación

Tags: postgresql

Estoy tratando de crear un *job* para *PostgreSQL*, lo primero que estoy haciendo es instalar el *pgAgent* por lo que estoy siguiendo esta [guía](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/pgagent_install.html#).

El problema es que me quedo en:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgagent;
```

Y me aparece el mensaje de error:

> ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/pgagent.control": No existe el archivo o el directorio SQL state: 58P01

Entiendo que este paso es crítico ya que te crea el esquema que luego utilizara *pgAgent*.

He probado creando el archivo copiando [esto](https://github.com/postgres/pgagent/blob/master/pgagent.control.in), pero que va, me tira otro error (tenía que probarlo).

Decir también que tengo el *pgAgent* instalado.

Estoy utilizando Ubuntu 12.04 y postgresql 9.1.24

Comment: Podría ser un error de permisos, qué permisos tiene el usuario de postgresql? tiene acceso desde el server a esa carpeta?

Comment: La cosa es que entro en esa carpeta y el fichero no existe. si que tiene acceso, por que si lo creo yo, lo llega a utilizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al final no me ha servido de mucho el tutorial que estaba siguiendo.

Haciendo búsqueda, encontré [esto](http://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/19.html), que lo he solucionado con:

1. Creando el lenguaje `plsql`

   ```
   CREATE TRUSTED PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
       HANDLER plpgsql_call_handler
       VALIDATOR plpgsql_validator;
   ```
2. Ejecutando el contenido del archivo: `pgagent.sql`. Que lo he encontrado en: `/usr/share/pgAdmin3/pgagent.sql`. Por lo que solo he tenido que copiar el contenido y ejecutarlo como SQL normal.